# Filter a database using a date vector to generate average values within a range of ±3 days for each date in the vector?"

Tags: r

I have two databases, one containing monthly data and the other with daily values. My objective is to filter the daily database in such a way that I obtain the same dates as in the monthly database, but with a 7-day average (3 days before and 3 days after the monthly date).

From DB1, I've extracted a date vector:

```
fechas_vector <- c("1997-05-01", "1997-08-01", "1997-11-01", ... , "2003-08-01")`
```

And here's the structure of DB2:

```
year month   day     U     V     W date       U_mean V_mean W_mean ...
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> ...
 1  2002     1     1  3.67  4.03  5.48 2002-01-01   3.67   4.03   5.48 ...
 2  2002     1     2  2.71  6.31  6.94 2002-01-02   3.19   5.17   6.21 ...
 ...
```

My code is structured as follows:

```
result <- data.frame()  

for (ref_date in fechas_vector) {
  start_date <- ref_date - days(3)
  end_date <- ref_date + days(3)
  
  subset_db2 <- db2 %>%
    filter(date >= start_date, date <= end_date)
    
  if (nrow(subset_db2) > 0) {
    averaged_values <- sapply(subset_db2[, -1], function(column) {
      if (is.numeric(column)) {
        mean(column, na.rm = TRUE)
      } else {
        NA
      }
    })
    
    result_row <- c(ref_date, averaged_values)
    result <- rbind(result, result_row)
  }
}

col_names <- c("reference_date", colnames(subset_db2)[-1])
colnames(result) <- col_names
```

In summary, I'm attempting to generate a new dataset where I take each date from the fechas_vector, extract the corresponding ±3 day range of values from the daily database (DB2), calculate the average for each numeric column within that range, and then store these results in a new data frame named result.

However, I'm encountering some challenges or unexpected behavior with my code that I'd appreciate assistance with. Specifically, I'm unsure if the loop structure is optimal for this task and if there might be any issues with the filtering or averaging process. Your guidance and suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I think it would help to provide better example data. Use something like `dput(head(db2, 10))` to provide the first 10 rows of `db2`. Provide a complete data vector, not one with `...` and make sure the values match at least some of the values provided for `db2`. And provide some desired output. This strikes me as a problem that can probably better be solved by manipulating one data frame.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to handle this would be to take `fechas_vector` and turn it into a dataset that has all relevant days.  For example, you could do the following, making an observation for each row and then for each observation, make a sequence of dates from t-3 to t+3:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

fechas_vector = c("2022-12-01", "2023-01-04", "2023-01-06", "2023-01-12")
db1 <- tibble(date = ymd(fechas_vector)) %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(obs) %>% 
  reframe(date = seq(date -days(3), date + days(3), by="1 day"))
```

Then, I'll make a trial `db2` dataset that has similar features to the one above.

```r
db2 <- data.frame(
  year = rep(2023, 15), 
  month = rep(1, 15), 
  day = 1:15, 
  x = rnorm(15),
  y=rnorm(15), 
  z=rnorm(15)
)
```

Finally, you can use `left_join()` from `dplyr` to put `db1` and `db2` together matching up all relevant dates from `db2` onto the required dates from `db1`.  Then you can just summarize across `date` and all the numeric columns taking the mean. You can see that for dates from `db1` that don't have dates in `db2`, you'll get missing values (like in the first row), otherwise you'll get the mean.

```r
db1 <- left_join(db1, 
                 db2 %>% 
                   mutate(date = ymd(paste(year,
                                           month,
                                           day, 
                                           sep="-"))))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(date)`

db1 %>% 
  group_by(obs) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(date, x:z), ~mean(.x, na.rm=TRUE)))
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>     obs date              x        y        z
#>   <int> <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1 2022-12-01 NaN      NaN      NaN     
#> 2     2 2023-01-04   0.0438   0.0632   0.778 
#> 3     3 2023-01-06   0.0705   0.0580   0.561 
#> 4     4 2023-01-12   0.137   -0.115   -0.0515
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Wow, that was quick and effective. Thank you so much for the response. It was the solution I was looking for.